# Typescript: incorrect type checking for function that returns void

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Could someone explain to me why the code I have written below does not seem to distinguish the following two types:

[1] `() => void` (a function type that takes no arguments returns nothing)

[2] `() => () => void` (a function that takes no arguments and returns a function that takes no arguments and returns nothing).

For example:

```
const function2 = (): () => void => {
  return (): void => {};
};

export const function1 = (arg: () => void): void => {
  console.log(arg);
};

function1(function2); // Should NOT pass type checker as the return type is not void
function1(function2()); // Should pass type checker
```

Or, could someone enlighten me on how to make `function1(function2)` throw a Typescript compile error.

Comment: [Why are functions returning non-`void` assignable to function returning `void`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-returning-non-void-assignable-to-function-returning-void)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function `function1` does not process the result (`void` cannot be processed) of `arg` function. Therefore compiler allows functions returning something. If you make `arg` to be function returning some processable result it will warn also in case of passing function returning another function with correct return type.